# The SSL certificate used to load adsafeprotected.com will be distrusted in M66

Tags: bug, advertising

The following 3 warnings appear in JS Console in Google Chrome Canary 63.x web-browser:

> The SSL certificate used to load https://fw.adsafeprotected.com/rjss/www.googletagservices.com/X/Y/dcm/dcmads.js will be distrusted in M66. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading this resource. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.
>   container.html:1
>
> The SSL certificate used to load https://dt.adsafeprotected.com/dt?advEntityId=X&asId=Y&tv={c:qxrJ0j,pingTime:-3,time:80,type:v,env:{sf:1},rt:1,cb:0,th:0,es:0,sa:1,sc:0,ha:1,gm:0,fif:0,slTimes:{i:0,o:80,n:77,pp:0,pm:0},slEvents:[{sl:n,t:42,wc:0.0.1440.900,ac:NaN.NaN.300.250,am:i,cc:NaN.NaN.300.250,piv:-1,obst:0,th:0,reas:,cmps:1,bkn:{piv:[60~1],as:[60~300.250]}},{sl:o,t:77,wc:0.0.1440.900,ac:NaN.NaN.300.250,am:i,cc:NaN.NaN.300.250,piv:0,obst:0,th:0,reas:l,cmps:1,bkn:{piv:[4~0],as:[4~300.250]}}],slEventCount:2,em:true,fr:false,uf:0,e:,tt:rjss,dtt:0,fm:qxy6C6k+11*.114626-18813284|12,idMap:11*}&br=c will be distrusted in M66. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading this resource. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.
>   container.html:1
>
> The SSL certificate used to load https://dt.adsafeprotected.com/dt?advEntityId=X&asId=Y&tv={c:qxrJ0v,pingTime:-2,time:91,type:a,sca:{dfp:{df:4,sz:300.250,dom:ins}},env:{pom:1},rt:1,cb:0,th:0,es:0,sa:1,sc:0,ha:1,gm:0,fif:0,slTimes:{i:0,o:91,n:77,pp:0,pm:0},slEvents:[{sl:n,t:42,wc:0.0.1440.900,ac:NaN.NaN.300.250,am:i,cc:NaN.NaN.300.250,piv:-1,obst:0,th:0,reas:,cmps:1,bkn:{piv:[60~1],as:[60~300.250]}},{sl:o,t:77,wc:0.0.1440.900,ac:NaN.NaN.300.250,am:i,cc:NaN.NaN.300.250,piv:0,obst:0,th:0,reas:l,cmps:1,bkn:{piv:[14~0],as:[14~300.250]}}],slEventCount:2,em:true,fr:false,uf:0,e:,tt:rjss,dtt:0,fm:qxy6C6k+11*.114626-18813284|12,idMap:11*,pd:s3fi.widevinecdmadapter,sinceFw:41,readyFired:false}&br=c will be distrusted in M66. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading this resource. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information.

<sup>Note: `X`, `Y` are the placeholders in order to remove the previous data.</sup>

This happens on every page on https://stackoverflow.com/, however I didn't see it on meta site.

I believe this is the future warning that the SSL certificate used by adsafeprotected.com would be distrusted in Chrome 66.x, so I'm not sure whether any action should be taken at this point.

See: [Chrome’s Plan to Distrust Symantec Certificates](http://Chrome%E2%80%99s%20Plan%20to%20Distrust%20Symantec%20Certificates):

> Starting with Chrome 66, Chrome will remove trust in Symantec-issued certificates issued prior to June 1, 2016. Chrome 66 is currently scheduled to be released to Chrome Beta users on March 15, 2018 and to Chrome Stable users around April 17, 2018.
>
> If you are a site operator with a certificate issued by a Symantec CA prior to June 1, 2016, then prior to the release of Chrome 66, you will need to replace the existing certificate with a new certificate from any Certificate Authority trusted by Chrome.

Comment: As the domain isn't owned by SE I guess their only option is to raise this with their vendor.

Comment: Maybe there is some library to upgrade (e.g. different endpoints). If not, this can be at least raised with the ad provider support.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I work in the Ad Ops team at SO. I've spoken to the client's vendor IAS (Integral Ad Sciences) and they have assured me they work very closely with Google, and this shouldn't be an issue, but I'm waiting on final confirmation. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: any update on the same?

Comment: Any update Denimjean?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder - this is the response IAS received from Google: "The article you linked to has to do with website certificates, rather than Google technology certifications. From a Google Certification standpoint, this will not affect your certified technologies nor will you need to request an updated certification from us. However, website operators using Symantec-issued TLS server certificates will need to review the instructions in the article to ensure they are prepared for Chrome 'distrust' of the TLS server certificates."